# CSS Media Queries - Not Working at Correct Width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've set up a test with media queries to work like so:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    #global-wrapper-cp-fefc4ea514a255df2244eaccdabbb262 * {
        background: red !important;
    }
}
```

However, the CSS is effective from 666px to 716px:

[image]
[image]

My browser is at 100% zoom, so it cannot be this. I am using Chrome extension "Browser Width".

I'm hoping this is something simple that will leave me red faced. Can anybody offer any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Are there any other rules specifying a red background? When your viewport size is larger than 700px, the media query is no longer active, but there might be additional rules that enforce a red background. Always **create a minimal, verifiable and concrete example that reproduces your issue**, that usually helps a lot with troubleshooting.

Comment: Hey. Afraid not, this is the only rule I've put into place and nothing else is to have a red background. If I remove the rule, the red background does not occur at any width.

Comment: You have to test it inside responsive view section, currently it's showing `17px` scrollbar, after excluding this width you media query will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test it inside responsive view section, currently it's showing `17px` scroll-bar. After excluding this width, your media query will work.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I knew this would be stupidly simple. Thank you.